# Bunch update product attribute using api

Tags: magento2, webapi

I want to update product attributes via API, something like the import tool but can be posted automatically from another server.

The API to update single product `/V1/products/:sku` which uses the Product Repository has terrible performance (takes about 2 seconds per product on my server).

When running it should be able to update around 20000 products per day as fast as possible. I only need to update some specific attributes and stock qty. I know I can update them using SQL on the attribute tables, but tinkering around that would be dangerous because it is related to the system indexes.

What's the right way to do that? Any suggestion is very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An extension for Magento 2 that introduces enhanced import functionality. The extension is installed and managed via Magento 2 admin panel, meaning that you can configure it from any place at any time, and you are not dependent on running applications.

You can refer to [this module](https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html). It can update according to the cron job.

Comment: I know, but we want to do it automatically. Whenever our external site has a change, we need to post it immediately to Magento site.